# I am getting an error when running the flutterfire configure command on my mac

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
Unhandled exception:
Exception: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'

#0      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:517:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (file:///Users/dylanguzman/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.6+1/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried :

```
flutterfire configure --project=test-app-egr423
```

Firebase configuration file lib/firebase_options.dart generated successfully with the following Firebase apps:

Comment: the safest way to do is to create your firebase project first then run flutterfire configure and choose the firebase project where you want to configure your  app.

Comment: is this solved ??

Comment: @sharsadkk, please check my solution. I could finally solve this.

Answer (score 16):

I was getting the same error when using `flutterfire` version `0.2.7` on my Macbook Air M1 when running `flutterfire configure`. In my case I solved this issue by opening the terminal and running the following command:

```bash
gem install xcodeproj
```

Or if running the command gives any permission errors:

```bash
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

I hope this solves the problem for you as well. I found my solution from [this](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/127) Github issue.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me, was the same as others have said. I had tried to install xcodeproj through brew and was having link issues, but I've installed it using

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

and now flutterfire configure is working.